# Получить отсортированный массив id (от большего к меньшему), просумировав и объединив объекты в массиве

Tags: сортировка

Всем здравствуйте!

Предыстория на всякий случай)) может подскажите лучшую реализацию задумки.
Есть таблица в базе данных (статистика посещения каждой публикации, записывается именно время проведённое посетителем на странице и id этой записи), для анализа берутся последние 100 записей в статистике. Хочу показывать на сайте самые популярные посты.

Имеется примерно такой массив:

```
`const arr = 
[
{id: 1, time: 4}, 
{id: 2, time: 2}, 
{id: 3, time: 5}, 
{id: 1, time: 6},
{id: 4, time: 7}, 
{id: 1, time: 4}, 
{id: 2, time: 3}, 
{id: 3, time: 5}, 
{id: 1, time: 4}, 
{id: 3, time: 8}, 
{id: 3, time: 5},
]`
```

Как то необходимо получить из него отсортированный (от большего к меньшему) массив id постов  именно по сумме времени прибывания на странице. Ну т.е. просуммировать время, объединить по id и отсортировать.

Потом по плану из таблицы постов по массиву этих id делать выборку из таблицы постов.
Нашёл решение на js, но немного не то

```
const res = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(el.id)) acc[el.id] = el.time;
  else acc[el.id] += el.time;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log('RESULT', res);
```

Целый день уже над этой задачей сижу и ничего не получается, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: В решении только сортировки нет, а так там правильно аггрегируются просмотры, осталось только отсортировать.

Comment: я если честно новичок совсем в программировании)) и там получается объект как я понимаю, А если поменять первоначальное состояние на [] массив оно перестаёт работать и вот не знаю как это сделать